# Analytics for Apache Hadoop - can I Import data by using Hadoop shell commands?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I'm trying to import data into my **Analytics for Apache Hadoop** instance using Hadoop shell commands.

The **Analytics for Apache Hadoop** bluemix documentation provides a link to BigInsight documentation in the related links section.  The link is: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.welcome.doc/doc/welcome.html

I navigated to the following page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.import.doc/doc/data_rest_shell.html, where instructions are given for using the `hadoop fs` command line.

I tried the following command (replacing the hostname with my instance name):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://test.ibm.com:9000/<TargetDirPath>
```

However, the command timed out.

--

**Question:** Can I use the `hadoop fs` command as described in the BigInsights documentation with Analytics for Apache Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use the Hadoop shell commands.

The next best thing is to use the REST API, webHDFS.  The REST api is documented here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforHadoop/index.html#analyticsforhadoop_data